# VIM deleting/modifying HTML attributes

Tags: html, vim

I'm new to editing html with VIM. I'm using matchit, ultisnips and surround to help me along the way.

One area which I can't seem to accomplish easily is editing attributes.

I want to go from: (cursor is |)

```
<input type="submit|" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name">
```

to:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button">
```

What is the fastest way to do this?
Right now, I'm doing a lot of 'f' based searches.

Comment: To delete an entire attribute I use `dwxda"`. `dw` to delete the attribute name, `x` to delete the `=`, then `da"` to delete everything inside the quotes, and the quotes themselves.

Comment: To delete an entire attribute I use `dW` (this includes the name, the `=` and the quoted value). **Unless** it's the last attribute before the tag's closing `>`. In that case I'd use `2df"` or @Will's solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible solutions

```
wd2W
```

This method requires counting so maybe you would rather do `wdW` and just hit `.` until it is correct.

```
wd/ id<cr>
```

Moves to the next word so the start of `name=".."` the delete with `d` til `/ id`. This solution can also delete across lines. You can use `/...` with other operators as well, e.g. `c`, `y`, and `=`.

Of course you can do the method you are using currently with `f` and just repeat with `.`

Answer (score 8):

I usually just use **dW**, which deletes the name, equals character and the value in parenthesis (including the parenthesis).

In some cases if I want to delete the rest of attributes to the end of the HTML tag I'm using **dt/** (delete everything until you find / which is the end of input tag <input ... />)

Answer (score 6):

I was also looking for a solution for this, and using w and W wasn't working great for me when dealing with AngularJS where you can have attributes like this:

```
<input ng-show="product.inUse" ng-model="product.customerPrice" />
```

What I've started doing is moving my cursor to the whitespace before the attribute, for example here:

```
<input| ng-show="product.inUse" ng-model="product.customerPrice" />
```

Then press d2f" (y instead of d for copying), which gives me:

```
<input| ng-model="product.customerPrice" />
```

It will look for a " character two times and delete everything including the last one.

Answer (score 2):

For your example, I would use: `wdw.....wwci"submit_button`

- `w` to move at the end of the current w
- `dw` to erase a "word"
- then `.` to repeat the last command and erase as many word as you want.
- `ww` to move quickly between the "
- `ci"` to change content inside "
- `submit_button`
- <kbd>ESC</kbd>

See `:help text-objects` for more explanation on `ciw`. (please not there is a `tag` text object so you can things like `cit` to change content of a tag quickly.

You could probably use something like `wd4w` but you have to be sure beforehand that you want to erase 4 words.

Have you heard about [Zencoding.vim](http://mattn.github.com/zencoding-vim/) ?

This is plugin designed to quickly write html or css.

I am not sure there are features to edit, but to write new codes it beats everything.

Comment: Thanks; I'll try Zencoding for html generation.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `ci>` and retype the form. Lot of times my snippets have tons of attributes I don't need like `<form action="">` so `ci>` blows it up and lets me start from scratch when I need to. I find it faster.

Answer (score 0):

`<input type="submit" name="some_name" value="" id="some_name">`

You can also use `dt>`, it will delete until the character `>`